# Auto filter without using button and ajax in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have 3 tables:

```
Type: id, name
Level: id, name
Question: id, content, type_id, level_id
```

I've done filter function with "Filter" button. But now, what I want is that when I filter, data will be loaded into table automatically without using button. How can I do?

Here is my code using button

FilterController:

```
public function filter(Request $request){
        $types = Type::all();
        $levels = Level::all();
        $model = Question::where('id', '>', 0);

        if (isset($request->type))
            $model = $model->where('type_id', $request->type);
        if (isset($request->level))
            $model = $model->where('level_id', $request->level);

        $data = $model->paginate(999)->appends(request()->query());

        return view('filter', compact( 'data', 'request', 'types','levels'));
    }
```

filter.blade.php

```
<form method="get">
    <select name="type">
        <option value="">All Types</option>
        @foreach ($types as $item)
            <option value="{{ $item->id }}" @if ($request->type == $item->id) selected @endif>{{ $item->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <select name="level">
        <option value="">All Levels</option>
        @foreach ($levels as $item)
            <option value="{{ $item->id }}" @if ($request->level == $item->id) selected @endif>{{ $item->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Filter</button>
</form>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Content</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($data as $q)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $q->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $q->content }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Comment: Then you should use ajax to do that. Vue.js could fulfill your needs easily.

Comment: Is anything else without using ajax?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply submit the form when your select values change:

```html
<select onchange="this.form.submit()">
    ...
</select>
```

Or if you didn’t want to use a form, assuming your path is `/questions` and you've set the `APP_URL` property in your .env file, you could do something similar to the following:

```
<select name="type" onchange="window.location.href = this.value">
    <option value="{{ url('questions') }}">All types</option>
    @foreach($types as $type)
        <option value="{{ url('questions') }}?type={{ $type->id }}"{{ request('type') == $type->id ? ' selected' : '' }}>
            {{ $type->name }}
        </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

If you want the currently selected level to stay selected when you filter by type, you could change your option value to the following:

```
<option value="{{ url('questions') . '?' . (request()->filled('level') ? 'level=' . request('level') . '&' : '') . 'type=' . request('type') }}">
    {{ $type->name }}
</option>
```

Answered on my phone so there may be broken syntax.

Comment: Thanks. I used your 1st way. But url still change. I want that url doesn't change when I filter

Comment: Example: url must be abc.local/filter, not abc.local/filter?type=1&level=1

Comment: You could change the method of the form to `post` to and obviously update your routes file to catch the request and point it to the filter method. Otherwise Ajax would be the way to go.

Comment: Could you show detail code when change method of the form to post please?